# Google Cloud PubSub: How to read only latest records

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow

In Kafka there is 2 settings `earliest` and `latest` where you either read from the earliest offset (0) of the topic or the latest event (useful for realtime)

I am now using PubSub with Dataflow and Beam, but by default the job seems to read from earliest every time it starts up.  How to configure this so that it reads only the latest records?

As `latest` is the default value in Kafka, can anyone explain why this is not easily possible in Pub/Sub ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google PubSub - getting last message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773234/google-pubsub-getting-last-message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the definition of latest? Indeed, with Beam, the PubsubIO reader is an unbounded read. That's mean, there is no end, there is always a more recent after the recent!

So, this was for the philosophical part. In fact, you have to define, the latest compare to what. With beam, you can use [windowing](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing). And then, you can say, *in a window of 5 minutes, I would like to process the last one*. Here the definition of the latest is correct and you can implement this.

Comment: I am familiar with windowing but it does not fit in my case.  If I restart an app I dont want it to process all messages on a topic from the beginning, only the new messages that arrive after app has been started. Is this possible in Beam / PubSub?

Comment: In this case, the seek in the best solution. Set the seek to Now, and launch your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the seek option: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/seek

It's still a bit rudimentary because you need to determine a timestamp or snapshot.

I guess the Apache Beam option would be using withTimestampAttribute

https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.15.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubIO.Read.html#withTimestampAttribute-java.lang.String-

Comment: According to linked documentation, _seek API_ acknowledges messages older than given timestamp. So yes, you'll read the last messages then **but you'll lose older ones, since they will be acknowledged**. I don't think that's what OP wants to achieve.

Comment: You can avoid losing older messages by setting the [retain-acked-messages](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/replay-qs#seek_to_a_timestamp) feature. This would ensure the messages aren't lost, but to receive them, you would have to seek back to earlier.